# Azure Data Factory V2 bug in Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset when dataset type json

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

When I try to use Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset and dataset type is "Json" in incoming file for some reason in ADFV2 code changed so that type = "Dataset" and ADFV2 says files is corrupted.

This is the end result in ADFV2:

```
"properties": {
    "type": "Dataset",
    "typeProperties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
            "fileName": "somefile",
            "folderPath": "folder/files",
            "fileSystem": "source-data"
        },
```

If I modify file in ADFV2 value "Dataset" back to "Json" its not corrupted anymore. See above.

```
"properties": {
    "type": "Json",
    "typeProperties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
            "fileName": "somefile",
            "folderPath": "folder/files",
            "fileSystem": "source-data"
        },
```

Is there bug in parser?

Comment: Could you please post the entire json file you are trying to upload as a dataset?

Comment: ``{
    "name": "dataset",
    "properties": {
  "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "ls_adls",
   "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
          },
          "annotations": [],
          "type": "Json",
           "typeProperties": {
              "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName":  "somefile.json",
                "folderPath":"folder/files",
                "fileSystem": "source-data"
                },
                "encodingName": "Windows-1252"
            }
        }
    }``

Answer (score 1):

The type in the dataset json tells data factory which kind of storage you are accessing. It looks like you are trying to access a blob storage or a data lake v2. In those cases, the type attribute must be set to:

AzureBlobStorageLocation if its a blob storage as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#dataset-properties

AzureBlobFSLocation if its a lake v2 as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#dataset-properties

You can also check out an example json if you scroll down a bit in those links.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I can confirm this is a bug in the Az/AzureRM PowerShell module, which appears to have been fixed as of Az version 2.5.0 (at least, possibly earlier).

I hit the same problem when trying to define a dataset with a type 'Binary'. The JSON I provided had it correct, but when it was actually created the type was 'Dataset'. When playing around I realized it was only happening on my Windows VM, running the Az module version 2.1.0. Running from my Linux OS with Az version 2.5.0 worked fine. On updating my Windows VM to 2.6.0 the problem went away.

Comment: You are correct. Microsoft told me that AzureRM poweshell module is deprecated and not developed anymore and if AzureAz module is used this bug doesn’t exists anymore. Thanks everyone one fast reply.